# local 'variable' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

I wrote a signal that changes a field inside user model. it works fine but when a user registers for the first time it gives me this error:

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'scientific' referenced before assignment
```

this is my signal:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='progress_change')
def progress(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    if ScientificInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        scientific = ScientificInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if ReligiousInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        religious = ReligiousInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if PsychologicInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        psychological = PsychologicInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if InvestigationInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        investigation = InvestigationInfo.objects.get(user=user)

    if scientific.is_interviewed == False and religious.is_interviewed == False and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == False and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[2][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[3][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == True and  investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[4][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == True and investigation.is_interviewed == True:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[5][0]
```

I think the pre_save is causing the issue because when I change it to post_save users can register but the signal wont work then. what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you defined `scientific` inside `if` statement and when accessed in `if scientific.is_interviewed == False` it says it is not defined.So you have to define `scientific` variable before `if` statement with `default` value.

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid='progress_change')
def progress(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    user = instance
    scientific = religious = psychological = investigation = None #< ----- initialize variable
    if ScientificInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        scientific = ScientificInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if ReligiousInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        religious = ReligiousInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if PsychologicInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        psychological = PsychologicInfo.objects.get(user=user)
    if InvestigationInfo.objects.filter(user=user).exists():
        investigation = InvestigationInfo.objects.get(user=user)]

    if scientific.is_interviewed == False and religious.is_interviewed == False and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[1][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == False and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[2][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == False and investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[3][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == True and  investigation.is_interviewed == False:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[4][0]
    if scientific.is_interviewed == True and religious.is_interviewed == True and psychological.is_interviewed == True and investigation.is_interviewed == True:
        user.progress_level = USER_PROGRESS_LEVELS[5][0]
```